# WSO2 - java.sql.SQLException: no suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle

Tags: java, wso2, ojdbc

Do you ever face this problem on WSO2?

Reason: `java.sql.SQLException: no suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle`

I would like to connection with Oracle Database vai wso2 (DBlookup Mediator).

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VahUk.png)

**Log Detail**

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.109:1521/CMSUAT3
No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.109:1521/CMSUAT3
  java.base/java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1607)
  org.wso2.integrationstudio.gmf.esb.presentation.DependencyProvider.createMultiStatus(DependencyProvider.java:1657)
  org.wso2.integrationstudio.gmf.esb.presentation.DependencyProvider.testConnecton(DependencyProvider.java:1354)
  org.wso2.integrationstudio.gmf.esb.presentation.DependencyProvider$10.handleEvent(DependencyProvider.java:954)
  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4243)
  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1060)
  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4060)
  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3632)
  org.wso2.integrationstudio.gmf.esb.presentation.DependencyProvider.open(DependencyProvider.java:1037)
  org.wso2.integrationstudio.gmf.esb.parts.forms.DBLookupMediatorPropertiesEditionPartForm$10$1$1.run(DBLookupMediatorPropertiesEditionPartForm.java:702)
  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:40)
  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:185)
  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4035)
  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3635)
  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1154)
  org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1045)
  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
  org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
  org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
  org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
  org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
  java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
```

Driver using: `ojdbc11.jar`

Please help comment :)

Comment: Not sure why you are getting this, you can update the Integration Studio to the latest version. If that doesn't work you can ignore this as this will not affect the functionality when you deploy the actual service to the runtime.

Comment: I already try brother. Let me try to search more. By the way thank you for your comment :)